# iOS: webView delegate methods not always called

Tags: iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, uiwebview, back-button

I want to set the back / forward button for my web view, so I check for canGoBack, canGoForward status in all 4 of the web view delegate methods. The delegate is set properly, and the methods are called in most cases. However, in a few cases they aren't called:

- When I call [webView goBack] (for a certain links)
- When I click to a link, go back, then click that link again (again, for a certain links).

I suspect it has something to do with the jquery mobile library or the html/css used in that page. However, Safari back button works properly.

So how can I track the back / forward button status, apart from making a timer?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're missing `webViewDidFinishLoading` reset?

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    webBack.enabled = [webView canGoBack];
    webForward.enabled = [webView canGoForward];
}
```

Comment: No I wasn't, this was set and works properly for the majority of websites, except a few (you can test with the problem link here: http://m.recette.novaplanet.com/mobile/home)

Comment: All right, will test in a sec. Edit: You're right, it doesn't work for me either. Interesting.

Comment: At least `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` is called, so you can detect it that way. There's gotta be a way to make it call webViewDidFinishLoad: though....

Comment: shouldStartLoadWithRequest isn't called when I call [webView goBack];. It isn't called when I re-click a link neither (maybe there is some kind of cache mechanism).

Comment: This is the deal: it won't load cached pages (as you suggest) but it also won't load pages which have the same URL. The URL in your link goes from http://.../home/ to .../home/#foo/bar which in URL speak is the same URL as /home/ but with a bookmark foo/bar. Not sure yet how to solve the issue though.

Comment: You can probably simulate the back/forward part by simply counting the number of DidFinishLoad: calls, decrementing the number when they click to go forward. So hacky though. :/

Comment: Hey, I just realized it may be possible to KVO 'request' in the web view. I'm off to bed but if that works it may be the answer to everything.

Comment: I also thought of counting the number of calls manually and store the links in a stack, but the didFinishLoad: method isn't always called so it doesn't work. KVO is an interesting idea, but apparently webview.request is not observable.

Comment: Right now my work around is to use a timer and check the canGoBack value every 0.5 seconds. To retrieve the current url, I also have to use stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location.href", since it's impossible to use the delegate methods to track the URL. It works well so far, but obviously not the optimal way. There are many websites which use the # stuff for navigation, so it's a shame UIWebView can't handle it though, the WebView callbacks in Android didn't have any problem with it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17767/discussion-between-kalle-and-enzo-tran)